# MySQL GROUP BY fields mismatch

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

**Is there any way to do this simple thing without two sub-queries?**

This is my basic data:

```
SELECT order_detail_id, product_id, MAX(paid_price) AS max_price, order_id
FROM t_order_details
WHERE order_id = 7 OR order_id = 8
GROUP BY order_id
```

[simple select result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SpLf.jpg)

I want select order_detail_id and product_id with maximum price, in order 7 and same thing in order 8. It seems that the data do not match row

```
SELECT order_detail_id, product_id, MAX(paid_price) AS max_price, order_id
FROM t_order_details
WHERE order_id = 7 OR order_id = 8
GROUP BY order_id
```

[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlnEl.jpg)

This is my solution with two sub-queries.

```
SELECT order_detail_id, product_id, paid_price, order_id
FROM t_order_details
WHERE paid_price IN (
    SELECT MAX(paid_price) AS max_price
    FROM t_order_details
    WHERE order_id = 7 OR order_id = 8
    GROUP BY order_id)
AND order_id IN (
    SELECT order_id
    FROM t_order_details
    WHERE order_id = 7 OR order_id = 8
    GROUP BY order_id)
GROUP BY order_id
```

But I think there should be more natural way to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following;)

```
SELECT T1.order_detail_id, T1.product_id, T1.paid_price, T1.order_id
FROM t_order_details T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(paid_price) AS paid_price, order_id
    FROM t_order_details
    WHERE order_id IN (7, 8)
    GROUP BY order_id
) T2 ON T1.order_id = T2.order_id AND T1.paid_price = T2.paid_price
WHERE T1.order_id IN (7, 8)
```

**Edited(Without Subquery):**

```
SELECT T1.order_detail_id, T1.product_id, T1.paid_price, T1.order_id
FROM t_order_details T1
INNER JOIN t_order_details T2
ON T1.order_id = T2.order_id AND T1.paid_price <= T2.paid_price
WHERE T1.order_id IN (7, 8)
GROUP BY T1.order_id, T1.order_detail_id, T1.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 1
```

Comment: Works! This is better than mine. But I hope that can be done without any subqueries. Because it is a very common problem

Comment: @AndreyKudriavtsev Check the **Edited** part check if it works or not please.